# syntax error when installing auth_mellon module on Apache

Tags: 16.04, apache2, authentication, webserver

I need to compile the module auth_mellon and I am using autoconf
but when I run this command

```
./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs
```

I am getting this

```
./configure: line 3138: syntax error near unexpected token `LASSO,'
```

and

```
./configure: line 3138: `PKG_CHECK_MODULES(LASSO, lasso)'
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Have a look at this:https://github.com/UNINETT/mod_auth_mellon/issues/96

Comment: yes i saw it but I am not missing pkg-config, syntax error when installing auth_mellon module on Apache

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
# apt-get install liblasso3 liblasso3-dev
# apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
# aclocal
# ./autogen.sh
# ./configure
# make
# make install
```

It works on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.